# My HttpGet function leads to the wrong page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm currently working on an C# ASP.NET project, but i'm quite a newbie in html/css. My question is:

On the page : `"http://localhost:27253/Default/TcpDump/"`, I've a button which activate the function "SimonTest" : When I click on it, it brings me on the page : `"http://localhost:27253/Default/TcpDump/SimonTest/2/1"`. But what the program should do is : (1) execute the function "SimonTest" and (2) brings me back to the `"http://localhost:27253/Default/TcpDump/SimonTest/2/1"`. Any idea?

Note : when I manually return to the first page, the button tries to bring me to `"http://localhost:27253/Default/TcpDump/TcpDump/SimonTest/2/1"`

Here is my HttpGet function code

```
namespace Serene5.Default.Pages
{
    using Serenity;
    using Serenity.Data;
    using Serenity.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data;

    [RoutePrefix("Default/TcpDump"), Route("{action=index}")]
    [PageAuthorize(typeof(Entities.TcpDumpRow))]
    public class TcpDumpController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("~/Modules/Default/TcpDump/TcpDumpIndex.cshtml");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("SimonTest/{id=0}/{obj=0}")]
        public ActionResult SimonTest(int id, int obj)
        {
            string[] listColumns = new string[] { "TimeStp", "IdTransmission", "IdSource", "IdDestination", "PortSource", "PortDestination", "ToTheRight", "ToTheLeft" };
            SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(LocalDb)\MSSqlLocalDB;Integrated security=SSPI;database=Serene5_Default_v1");
            string listDb = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [Serene5_Default_v1].[tcpdump].[TCPDump] WHERE IdTransmission = {0}", obj);
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(listDb, myConn);
            string command = "INSERT INTO Serene5_Default_v1.tcpdump.";
            if (id == 1)
            {
                command += "Errors (";
            }
            else
            {
                command += "Regeln (";
            }
            string temp = "(";
            myConn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    command += reader[i] + ",";
                    temp += listColumns[i] + ",";


                }
                command += reader[reader.FieldCount - 1];
                temp += listColumns[reader.FieldCount - 1];
            }

            reader.Close();
            command += ") INTO " + temp + ");";
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(command);
            SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(listDb, myConn);

            myCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Commande exécutée");
            myCommand2.Dispose();




            myConn.Close();
            return View("~/Modules/Default/TcpDump/SimonTest.cshtml");
        }
    }
}
```

The TcpDumpIndex.cshtml contains :

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = Serenity.LocalText.Get("Db.Default.TcpDump.EntityPlural");
}

<div id="GridDiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function () {
        new Serene5.Default.TcpDumpGrid($('#GridDiv'), {}).init();

        Q.initFullHeightGridPage($('#GridDiv'));
    });
</script>
```

I am not really aware of what it means, a guy just told me to put this line in my code in order to refresh my page.

If that can help, here is the code of the file containing the button :

```
namespace Serene5.Default {

    @Serenity.Decorators.registerClass()
    export class TcpDumpGrid extends Serenity.EntityGrid<TcpDumpRow, any> {
        protected getColumnsKey() { return 'Default.TcpDump'; }
        protected getDialogType() { return TcpDumpDialog; }
        protected getIdProperty() { return TcpDumpRow.idProperty; }
        protected getLocalTextPrefix() { return TcpDumpRow.localTextPrefix; }
        protected getService() { return TcpDumpService.baseUrl; }

        constructor(container: JQuery) {
            super(container);
        }
        protected getColumns(): Slick.Column[] {

            var columns = super.getColumns();

            var fld = TcpDumpRow.Fields;
            var time = $.now();

            columns.unshift(
                {
                    field: "Objekte",
                    name: "Objekte",
                    format: ctx => {
                        var item = ctx.item;  //data for that row
                        return "<a class='modal-link' href='TcpDump/SimonTest/1/" + item.IdTransmission + "' title='Gewöhnlich'><i class='fa fa-check-circle-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
                    },
                    width: 120,
                    minWidth: 120,
                    maxWidth: 150
                });

            columns.unshift(
                {
                    field: "Objekte",
                    name: "Objekte",
                    format: ctx => {
                        var item = ctx.item;  //data for that row
                        return "<a class='modal-link' href='TcpDump/SimonTest/2/" + item.IdTransmission + "' title='Seltsam'><i class='fa fa-times-circle-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>";
                    },
                    width: 120,
                    minWidth: 120,
                    maxWidth: 150
                });
            return columns
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification your action method `SimonTest` returning view as

```
return View("~/Modules/Default/TcpDump/TcpDumpIndex.cshtml");
```

Shouldn't it be

```
return View("~/Modules/Default/TcpDump/SimonTest.cshtml");
```

Unless you named it that way? Also can you post code from `RouteConfig` and Did you added any Route on Controller level?

Please edit your post, so I can understand better what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I explicited the content of TcpDumpIndex ^^ ! I don't have any files named "SimonTest.cshtml", I'm using a controller, my function is in a file named "TcpDumpPage.cs"